# Python efficient way to write nested if-else inside nested for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm working on a code challenge in which I have to reduce the execution time as much as possible, the only thing I able to find where I can make an improvement is a nested if-else statement inside a nested for-loop but I'm not sure how it can be improvided.

Here's my code:

```
mat = [[0] * n] * n
count = 0
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    count += 1
    for j in range(i,n+1,1):
        if i == j:
            pass
        else:
            if getEnemyStatus(mat, i, j):
               break
            else:
                if isEnemy(enemyDict, i, j):
                    setStatus(mat, i, j)
                    break
                else:
                    count += 1
```

> value of `n` can be from 1 to 10^5

Comment: Can you show the full code ?

Comment: full code is confidential, that's why not placed in the question.

Comment: Okay. Can't help you with just this part of the code...

Comment: How do you know that is the only thing that can be optimized? What are the Enemy and Status functions? Can you optimize them? What is mat?

Comment: `mat` is just a very simple `matrix`

Comment: Why is the code confidential? Isn't this a public challenge?

Comment: You can skip the first `if` condition by starting with `i+1` in `range`.

Comment: @AbdulRehman use the code snippet in an example scenario so that people can see what you are trying to do :)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes it's not a public one.

Comment: let me update the code and add a little bit more as I can.

Comment: @AbdulRehman Python doesn't have a matrix type. Assuming that the functions operate on it, can the data structure be optimized? E.g. a dict instead of lists or an additional lookup index?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have updated the code, you can see I have nested `for-loops` with `nested-if` statements. There's must be an improved form of these complex nested statements.

Comment: @beer44 how can I write that? can you write the code accordingly?

Comment: Using elsif instead of else if will reduce the nesting but not improve the performance. If you think you have to do these checks, then we can hardly tell you not to without knowing anything about them. Can you perhaps do the isEnemy check first and skip the getEmenyStatus otherwise?

Comment: I think it's necessary to set the `status`.

Comment: you should _really_ provide a [mcve] - perhaps at the very first you should get your code up and running (meaningful) before addressing performance. At least I doubt that `mat = [[0] * n] * n` does what you want because it creates a list of _list copies_, where if you change e.g. `m[0][1]` all `m[n][1]` will be changed accordingly. Or is this on purpose, known by you and tested?

Comment: @AbdulRehman now check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the first `if` `condition` by starting with `i+1` in `range`

```
for j in range(i+1, n+1, 1):
   # code here
```

Second, nested `if else` condition should be avoided with `elif` for reading purpose.

Update code should be like:

```
mat = [[0] * n] * n
count = 0
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    count += 1
    for j in range(i + 1, n + 1, 1):
        if getEnemyStatus(mat, i, j):
            break
        elif isEnemy(enemyDict, i, j):
            setStatus(mat, i, j)
            break
        else:
            count += 1
```

**NOTE**: Also if you can set the status `setStatus` in your `isEnemy function` then you can get more cleaner code:

```
mat = [[0] * n] * n
count = 0
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    count += 1
    for j in range(i + 1, n + 1, 1):
        if getEnemyStatus(mat, i, j) or isEnemy(enemyDict, i, j):
            break
        count += 1
```

Comment: @AbdulRehman For this particular code answer is Yes, now only one `if` condition will be check in `for` loop to break the internal loop. other performance now depends on `getEnemyStatus` and `isEnemy` function.